# How to create a numbering of the sections and subsections in beamer 1. 1a 1b

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, numbering

How to create a numbering of the sections and subsections in beamer 1. 1a 1b etc. in the frame and in table of contents?

I want change numbering to something like that:

1. First
   1a 
   1b
2. Second
   2a
   2b

I use theme called Antibes.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I am not completely sure what format you would like to achieve: Should e.g. the words "First" and "Second" be included or not? In addition, could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: The numbering style of section and subsection headers depends on the `beamer` theme you've chosen. Please tell us which theme you're working with.

Comment: Don't close, the other one is already closed as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Solution**

The following example shows how to achieve the desired toc:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{subsections numbered roman}{%
    \leavevmode\leftskip=1.5em\inserttocsectionnumber\@alph\inserttocsubsectionnumber\ %
    \inserttocsubsection\par}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered roman]

\begin{document}

    \frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{blub}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{blubblub}
\begin{frame}
    test
\end{frame}
\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\section{Test Section Three}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Problem**

But trying to modify the navigation bar, I am stuck at inserting the section numbers. I tried `\insertsectionheadnumber` but this unfortunatly does only work for other themes and not for `\useoutertheme{tree}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{subsections numbered roman}{%
    \leavevmode\leftskip=1.5em\inserttocsectionnumber\@alph\inserttocsubsectionnumber\ %
    \inserttocsubsection\par}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered roman]

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
        leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
        leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
        \ifbeamer@tree@showhooks
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsectionhead}%
        \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt%
        \hskip2pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
        \hskip1pt%
        \fi%
        \else%  
        \hskip6pt%
        \fi%
%       \insertsectionheadnumber % NOT WORKING
        \insertsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
        leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}%
        \ifbeamer@tree@showhooks
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsubsectionhead}%
        \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt%
        \hskip9.4pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
        \hskip1pt%
        \fi%
        \else%  
        \hskip12pt%
        \fi%
        \insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

    \frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{blub}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{blubblub}
\begin{frame}
    test
\end{frame}
\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\section{Test Section Three}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```